Oracle Execute Immediate into variable error: inconsistent datatypes
I have a script, that generates a dynamic statement to capture null and not null information about each column in a given table.
I was able to get the script to run initially, but only received the message PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
After some additional research, it looks like I need to put my dynamic query result into a separate variable and use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE to display the actual results from the execute immediate statement.
This is inside the loop, so it should only have one string that is a query as a result to run, so I didn't think BULK COLLECT INTO was the correct option.  That said, if it is, could someone provide a decent example, as what I did try to mimic failed even worse than what I have here.
Any advice is greatly appreciated!
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
    v_Schema ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.OWNER%TYPE;
    v_Table ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME%TYPE;
    v_columnName ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;
    v_columnPosition ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_ID%TYPE;
    v_dataType  ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE%TYPE;
    v_sql varchar2(4000);
    v_result varchar2(4000);
    
    CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_ID, DATA_TYPE FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE OWNER = '<my_schema>' AND table_name='<my_table>';

BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
      LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO v_Schema, v_Table, v_columnName, v_columnPosition, v_dataType;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        
        v_sql := 'SELECT  ''' 
        ||  v_Table  || ''' AS TableName '
        ||',''' || v_columnName || ''' AS ColumnName '
        ||',''' || TO_CHAR(v_columnPosition) || ''' AS ColumnPosition '
        ||',COUNT(CASE WHEN ' || v_columnName || ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CountNulls'
        ||',COUNT(CASE WHEN ' || v_columnName || ' IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS CountnonNulls '
        ||',COUNT(*) AS TotalRows '
        ||',COUNT(CASE WHEN ' || v_columnName || ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <> 0 THEN COUNT(*) ELSE .001 * 100 END AS PercentNull '
        ||',COUNT(CASE WHEN ' || v_columnName || ' IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) / CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <> 0 THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 0.1 END * 100 AS PercentNotNull '
        || 'FROM ' || v_Table;
    
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
    
      END LOOP;
      
    CLOSE c1;

END;



After some additional research, it looks like I need to put my dynamic query result into a separate variable and use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE to display the actual results from the execute immediate statement.

Yes, you do. Or, possibly, a record type with a field for each value. From the documentation:

If the dynamic SQL statement is a SELECT statement that can return at most one row, put out-bind variables (defines) in the INTO clause and in-bind variables in the USING clause.

At the moment your dynamic SQL isn't even being executed; if you don't execute it into something then it is parsed, but not executed; also from the documentation:

Note: If dynamic_sql_statement is a SELECT statement, and you omit both into_clause and bulk_collect_into_clause, then execute_immediate_statement never executes.


You already have some of the data you're selecting and can calculate the percentages later, so you only really need the three counts (total/null/not-null):
DECLARE
    v_Schema ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.OWNER%TYPE;
    v_Table ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME%TYPE;
    v_columnName ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;
    v_columnPosition ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_ID%TYPE;
    v_dataType  ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE%TYPE;
    v_sql varchar2(4000);
    v_result varchar2(4000);

    v_countNulls NUMBER;
    v_countNonNulls NUMBER;
    v_totalRows NUMBER;

    CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_ID, DATA_TYPE FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE OWNER = user AND table_name='T42';

BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
      LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO v_Schema, v_Table, v_columnName, v_columnPosition, v_dataType;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        
        v_sql := 'SELECT  '
        ||'COUNT(CASE WHEN ' || v_columnName || ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CountNulls'
        ||',COUNT(CASE WHEN ' || v_columnName || ' IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS CountnonNulls '
        ||',COUNT(*) AS TotalRows '
        || 'FROM ' || v_Table;
    
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql
        INTO v_countNulls, v_countNonNulls, v_totalRows;

        dbms_output.put_line(v_table || ' ' || v_columnName || ' ' || v_columnPosition
            || ' ' || v_countNulls || ' ' || v_countNonNulls || ' ' || v_totalRows
            || ' ' || v_countNulls/v_totalRows || ' ' || v_countNonNulls/v_totalRows);
   
      END LOOP;
      
    CLOSE c1;

END;
/

With a dummy sample table that then outputs:
T42 ID 1 0 5 5 0 1
T42 VALUE 2 2 3 5 .4 .6

... which isn't very helpful. You could potentially use a collection to build up the results and then pass that back to your caller, but that's a bit of a pain, particularly if you're just trying to run this manually to see the values.
Another way to tackle this is with a kind of XML trick. You can use what is essentially your current cursor to generate an XML representation of the results, as another kind of dynamic SQL:
select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
  'SELECT  ''' 
    || table_name  || ''' AS TableName '
    ||',''' || column_name || ''' AS ColumnName '
    ||',' || column_id || ' AS ColumnPosition '
    ||',COUNT(CASE WHEN "' || column_name || '" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CountNulls'
    ||',COUNT(CASE WHEN "' || column_name || '" IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS CountNonNulls '
    ||',COUNT(*) AS TotalRows '
    || 'FROM "' || owner || '"."' || table_name || '"') as xml
from all_tab_columns
where owner = user -- use your fixed value here instead of user
and table_name = 'T42';




XML




<ROWSET> <ROW>  <TABLENAME>T42</TABLENAME>  <COLUMNNAME>ID</COLUMNNAME>  <COLUMNPOSITION>1</COLUMNPOSITION>  <COUNTNULLS>0</COUNTNULLS>  <COUNTNONNULLS>5</COUNTNONNULLS>  <TOTALROWS>5</TOTALROWS> </ROW></ROWSET>


<ROWSET> <ROW>  <TABLENAME>T42</TABLENAME>  <COLUMNNAME>VALUE</COLUMNNAME>  <COLUMNPOSITION>2</COLUMNPOSITION>  <COUNTNULLS>2</COUNTNULLS>  <COUNTNONNULLS>3</COUNTNONNULLS>  <TOTALROWS>5</TOTALROWS> </ROW></ROWSET>



Which still doesn't look all that helpful; but you can then extract the data from that XML relationally, all in one query:
select x.TableName, x.columnName, x.ColumnPosition,
  x.CountNulls, x.CountNonNulls, x.TotalRows,
  x.CountNulls/x.TotalRows as PercentNull, x.CountNonNulls/x.TotalRows as PercentNonNull
from (
  select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
    'SELECT  ''' 
      || table_name  || ''' AS "TableName" '
      ||',''' || column_name || ''' AS "ColumnName" '
      ||',' || column_id || ' AS "ColumnPosition" '
      ||',COUNT(CASE WHEN "' || column_name || '" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "CountNulls"'
      ||',COUNT(CASE WHEN "' || column_name || '" IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS "CountNonNulls" '
      ||',COUNT(*) AS "TotalRows" '
      || 'FROM "' || owner || '"."' || table_name || '"') as xml
  from all_tab_columns
  where owner = user -- use your fixed value here instead of user
  and table_name = 'T42'
) t
cross apply xmltable(
  '/ROWSET/ROW'
  passing t.xml
  columns TableName varchar2(30) path 'TableName',
    ColumnName varchar2(30) path 'ColumnName',
    ColumnPosition number path 'ColumnPosition',
    CountNulls number path 'CountNulls',
    CountNonNulls number path 'CountNonNulls',
    TotalRows number path 'TotalRows'
) x
order by x.TableName, x.ColumnPosition;




TABLENAME
COLUMNNAME
COLUMNPOSITION
COUNTNULLS
COUNTNONNULLS
TOTALROWS
PERCENTNULL
PERCENTNONNULL




T42
ID
1
0
5
5
0
1


T42
VALUE
2
2
3
5
.4
.6



fiddle
As @p3consulting mentioned, all_tab_columns will include columns for views and other things, but as you are looking for a specific table that might not be an issue. (If you're always looking at your own schema you can use user_tab_columns to simplify the query slightly.)
it will also include invisible and system-generated columns, which you may or may not want. To ignore invisible columns just add a filter that column_id is not null.

I would do it a bit simpler and shorter like this:
DECLARE
    v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
    countAll INTEGER;
    countNotNull INTEGER;
     
    CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_ID, DATA_TYPE 
    FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
    WHERE OWNER = '<my_schema>' 
        AND table_name='<my_table>'
    ORDER BY COLUMN_ID;

BEGIN
    FOR aCol IN c1 LOOP
        v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT('||aCol.COLUMN_NAME||') '
          ||'FROM '||aCol.OWNER||'.'||aCol.TABLE_NAME; 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO countAll, countNotNull;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TableName = ' || aCol.TABLE_NAME);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ColumnName = ' || aCol.COLUMN_NAME);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ColumnPosition = ' || aCol.COLUMN_ID);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CountNulls = ' || to_char(countAll - countNotNull));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CountnonNulls = ' || countNotNull);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TotalRows = ' || countAll);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PercentNull = ' || TO_CHAR(100*(countAll - countNotNull)/NULLIF(countAll, 0)));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PercentNotNull = ' || TO_CHAR(100*countNotNull/NULLIF(countAll, 0)));
    END LOOP;
END; 

You only need to do some cosmetic for the output.
In case the performance matters, it is possible to create only one statement and run a single query (not tested):
DECLARE
   v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
   curid NUMBER;
   ret INTEGER;
BEGIN

   SELECT LISTAGG('COUNT('||COLUMN_NAME||') AS '||COLUMN_NAME||'notNull', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) 
   INTO v_sql 
   FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
   WHERE OWNER = '<my_schema>' 
      AND table_name='<my_table>';
   v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCount, '||v_sql|| ' FROM <my_table>';
   
   curid := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
   DBMS_SQL.PARSE(curid, v_sql, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
   ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(curid);
   DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(curid);
END;

This should return the result to your application like a normal SELECT statement. But you can also fetch the result into variables (not tested either):
DECLARE
    v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
    countAll INTEGER;
    countNotNull INTEGER;
     
    CURSOR cols IS 
    SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_ID, DATA_TYPE 
    FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
    WHERE OWNER = '<my_schema>' 
        AND table_name='<my_table>'
        AND COLUMN_ID > 1 -- because first column is fetched before the LOOP
    ORDER BY COLUMN_ID;

    curid NUMBER;
    ret INTEGER;

BEGIN

   SELECT LISTAGG('COUNT('||COLUMN_NAME||') AS '||COLUMN_NAME||'notNull', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) 
   INTO v_sql 
   FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
   WHERE OWNER = '<my_schema>' 
      AND table_name='<my_table>';
   v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCount, '||v_sql|| ' FROM <my_table>';

   curid := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
   DBMS_SQL.PARSE(curid, v_sql, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
   ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_AND_FETCH(curid);
   DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, 1, countAll);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TotalRows = ' || countAll);
   FOR aCol in cols LOOP
      DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, aCol.COLUMN_ID, countNotNull);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Count '||aCol.COLUMN_NAME||' NotNull = ' || countNuoNull);
         -- do some more with countNotNull and countAll
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(curid);
 
END;


By selecting from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS you will get VIEW and MATERIALIZED VIEW too, and the query will fail on all objects that are in invalid state, you should JOIN on ALL_TABLES and filter only the ones with "status = 'VALID'",
but you will still get the tables behind MVs, ...
To get back the results of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE you just add "INTO list_of_variables_you_need_to_declare".
Note also that you will get all the tables added by Oracle to handle JSON indexes, MV logs, full text indexes, error logging, etc. in general their name contain 1 or more '$', you may want to filter them out.
(And there is no need to re-select columns you already know: table_name, column_name, column_position, ...)
In any case adding EXCEPTION handling with appropriate logging will help you to understand edge cases.

I think your answer is not relevant, because query includes WHERE table_name='<my_table>'. Thus, it does not select accidentally anything wrong.

table_name from user_tab_colums which contains also info for views, just try "select table_name from user_tab_columns
join user_views on view_name = table_name"... if you have views in your schema of course...

Yes - but the OP is filtering on a specific table (or, to be fair, could be a view) name, they aren't looking at all entries for a schema. So your first and third paragraphs probably aren't relevant to this specific question, even if they're useful to note generally.
